# Some frogs form $2^{n-1}-1$ groups of $n$ frogs. If any frog can belong to multiple groups, prove the following

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

*This is a repost of a question I saw here that was deleted.*

Suppose that we have some number $m\geq 1$ of frogs. These frogs form $2^{n-1}-1$ groups, each consisting of $n>1$ frogs. Each frog can be part of multiple groups.

Suppose that each frog is colored red or blue. I want to show that, no matter how the frogs choose their groups, I can always assign blue or red to each frog such that each group contains at least one blue and one red frog.

**My attempt:** I thought about using induction. Here are my thinking steps for small $n$:

If $n=2$ then there is only one group with two frogs. So I can assign "blue" to one frog and "red" to the other.

If $n=3$ then there are three groups, each with three frogs. Now I already don't know what to do. I could easily brute force every possibility of the frogs to form groups, however that does not help my understanding of a potential induction step.

If the statement is true for $n$ then it is true for $n+1$: I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A random coloring will have the desired property with positive probability.

More precisely: color each frog red or blue with probability $1/2$ each. The probability that any given group of $n$ frogs is monochromatic (all red or all blue) is $1/2^{n-1}$. By linearity of expectation, the expected number of monochromatic groups is $(2^{n-1}-1)\cdot1/2^{n-1} = 1-1/2^{n-1}<1$. In particular, there must be a positive probability that there are $0$ monochromatic groups.

Comment: I have two questions regarding this answer: (1) I don't see how the probability can be independent from the total number of frogs. Indeed, if the total number of frogs is small, then there should be a lot of frogs in multiple groups so I think the probability to randomly get a monochromatic group should increase. If there are a lot of frogs (for instance none in multiple groups) then to me the probability to have a monochromatic group should be very low and likely to be the probability you computed. (2) I don't see how a probabilistic approach can prove that it is always possible.

Comment: @Jeanba: (1) the probability isn't independent of $m$, but we do not compute the exact probability of zero monochromatic groups, we only give a bound (namely that it is strictly less than 1). (2) the probability here ranges not over instances of the problem, it ranges over potential colorings: we prove *for a fixed frog-group distribution* that if we randomly color the frogs, there is non-zero chance of zero monochromatic groups. Therefore there must be at least one coloring that gives zero monochromatic groups.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does it mean that if there was one more group, i.e. if the expected nb of chromatic group was equal to one, then the entire demo would not work? Still feeling a little bit fuzzy to me, I ll try to work on it later to better understand the solution. I would have been so happy to see a solution in terms of matrices/dimensionality reduction/projection/etc showing for instance that there was to be a certain vector [c1,c2,..cm] ("ci" being the color of the frog i) solution of the problem. That's what I was trying to do on my side but to no avail so far.